# Sql - Excluir registros em massa - Delete em massa

Tags: sql, postgresql, runtime

Possuo uma tabela com cerca de 4 milhões de registros.

Qual o melhor método de excluir todos eles para obter o melhor tempo?
Indexar ajuda alguma coisa, tendo em vista que é apenas uma referencia para encontrar dados?

#### OBS

```
`DELETE FROM tb_name;` // Demorou em torno de 45min
```

Comment: Se puder use truncate. Qual banco é?

Comment: @rray postgresql.

Comment: Talvez fazer um drop na tabela e recriar seja mais rápido.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Truncate tem melhor performace que um delete sem where porque o primeiro não faz log das linhas apagadas enquanto o segundo faz isso para cada uma.

`TRUNCATE table nome` pode ser traduzido pelo banco como, apaguei os registros, truncate é DML.

`DELETE FROM nome`, é traduzido como, fiz log do registro 1, apaguei o registro 1 ... Até N. delete é um DML

Comment: Acho que TRUNCATE é logado por operação (ao invéz de registro - ou seja, você pode dar um ROLLBACK em um TRUNCATE), porém apenas DROP/CREATE é considerado DDL (mas posso estar errado! ;) ) - http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2010/10/12/tsql-tuesday-11-rolling-back-truncate-table.aspx

Comment: @OnoSendai, acho que me enganei, truncate parece ser um DDL no [oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/a/139633/1342547).

Comment: Ah, verdade - no Oracle o Truncate é tratado como DDL.

Comment: Ambas as respostas estão muito boas, e são complementares, estou na duvida em qual marcar como correto. Na sua você traz a questão do log ja na do @OnoSendai ele traz a questão do `CASCASE`.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert jogue uma moeda. =) A resposta do rray é excelente.

Answer (score 6):

Utilize TRUNCATE para excluir todos os registros.

```
TRUNCATE table;
```

É um método otimizado para exclusão completa de registros. Caso deseje propagar o efeito para tabelas que referenciam uma chave primária na tabela sofrendo TRUNCATE, utilize o parâmetro `CASCADE`;

```
TRUNCATE table CASCADE;
```

Fonte:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-truncate.html